# i am trying to make a rect move when i push a button in html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

i am trying to make a blue square move across the X axis when i click the button i made.
When i push the button nothing happens. I dont know what im doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    <title>tilte</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="draw">/button>
    <script>
        onload = function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
            var recX = 250
            var recY = 500
            var speedX = 5;
            draw()
            move()
            function draw() {
                ctx.fillStyle = "red"
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600)

                ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
                ctx.fillRect(recX, recY, 50, 50)
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `draw` must be a global function, otherwise an inline listener can't access it. You must also call the function from the inline listener, just referring doesn't do anything.

Comment: You need to put the canvas in the `<body>` (not the `<head>`) and to create a `move` function which updates the `rectX` variable and calls `draw()` on an interval. Then, use `addEventListener` to trigger that function on click

Answer (score -1):

change the onload function into onClick, and call "onClick();" from the button...

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<button onclick="onClick();">click to draw</button>

<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function onClick()
   {
   let recX = 250;
   let recY = 500;
   let speedX = 5;
   draw(recX,recY);
   move();
}
function draw(recX,recY) 
   {
   ctx.fillStyle = "red";
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
   ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
   ctx.fillRect(recX, recY, 50, 50);
}
</script>
```

is all you need

Comment: https://codepen.io/altruios/pen/qBZmEYq working codepen.io

Comment: working with exactly that code... so - when you say not working... is there an error... does a button even get drawn to a screen. please be more detailed.

Comment: so - looking above - in addition to my code being correct... I found out likely why it wasn't working for you.

Comment: just make sure that <canvas> tag is in the <body> tag and not the <head>tag... canvas goes in the body.

Comment: the canvas and shape will load but when i press the button nothing happens

Comment: go to the codepen.io in the link. it works in that link. exactly the code i have above.

when you click the button the canvas and shape on the canvas load. 

there is something not copied correctly, or something different in your code than what's posted - press f12 to get to the dev tools, navigate to the console, and see what(if any) errors are shown.

Comment: and your button is using `   onclick="onClick();"    ` correct?